# kustomize merge in kubernetes is overriding instead

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, devops, microk8s, kustomize

I am trying to use Kustomize to do a Patch Strategic merge on the following yaml.

y1:

```
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicy
metadata:
  name: storage-admin-policy
  namespace: cnrm-system
spec:
  resourceRef:
    apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    kind: IAMServiceAccount
    name: storage-admin
    namespace: cnrm-system
  bindings:
    - role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
      members:
        - serviceAccount:mysten-sui.svc.id.goog[monitoring/thanos-compactor]
```

y2:

```
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicy
metadata:
  name: storage-admin-policy
  namespace: cnrm-system
spec:
  resourceRef:
    apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    kind: IAMServiceAccount
    name: storage-admin
    namespace: cnrm-system
  bindings:
    - role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
      members:
        - serviceAccount:mysten-sui.svc.id.goog[monitoring/test-compactor]
```

I am using the following kustoomization file:

```
resources:
- y1.yaml

patchesStrategicMerge:
- y2.yaml
```

My requirement is that, I want the YAML to be clubbed something like this:

```
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicy
metadata:
  name: storage-admin-policy
  namespace: cnrm-system
spec:
  resourceRef:
    apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    kind: IAMServiceAccount
    name: storage-admin
    namespace: cnrm-system
  bindings:
    - role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
      members:
        - serviceAccount:mysten-sui.svc.id.goog[monitoring/test-compactor]
    - role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
      members:
        - serviceAccount:mysten-sui.svc.id.goog[monitoring/thanos-compactor]
```

Answer (score 0):

StrategicMerge cannot append to arbitrary lists as per https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/3265#issuecomment-733335803.

You could instead try a json6902 patch as shown here: [Patching list in kubernetes manifest with Kustomize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917460/patching-list-in-kubernetes-manifest-with-kustomize).

Comment: Thanks, it works. My workflow is designed in such a way that the jsonpatch is appended to to the kustomization.yaml multiple times. Is there any way that customization can skip duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to change the patch strategy in Kustomize using the [Kustomize openapi](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/openapi/) to merge lists.

However, this exact CR `iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1/IAMPolicy` will not work because according to [its schema](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/iam/iampolicy), the `bindings` field doesn't have a unique key to be used with `x-kubernetes-patch-merge-key`.

If it had something like this, it could work, but unfortunately, it doesn't have it.

```
bindings:
- id: xyz
  role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
  members:
    - serviceAccount:mysten-sui.svc.id.goog[monitoring/test-compactor]
```

More details about using OpenAPI in Kustomize: [Set OpenAPI patch strategy for Kubernetes Custom Resources](https://tech.aabouzaid.com/2022/11/set-openapi-patch-strategy-for-kubernetes-custom-resources-kustomize.html).

Answer (score 0):

I developed [Merger](https://github.com/aabouzaid/kustomize-plugin-merger), a Kustomize that makes merging much easier (using a schemaless StrategicMerge).

I've added your exact example to the [common use cases](https://github.com/aabouzaid/kustomize-plugin-merger#common-use-cases).

Here is how to do it with Merger using your case.

Files:

Assuming that your files `y1.yaml` and `y2.yaml` are already created in the same dir.

```
# kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

generators:
- merger.yaml
```

```
# merger.yaml
apiVersion: generators.kustomize.aabouzaid.com/v1alpha1
kind: Merger
metadata:
  name: merge
  annotations:
    # Containerized KRM function.
    config.kubernetes.io/function: |
      container:
        image: ghcr.io/aabouzaid/kustomize-generator-merger:1.1.0
        mounts:
        - type: bind
          src: ./
          dst: /mnt
spec:
  resources:
  - name: my-iam-policy
    input:
      method: overlay
      files:
        root: /mnt
        # The source overrides the destination.
        sources:
        - y1.yaml
        destination: y2.yaml
    merge:
      strategy: append
    output:
      format: raw
```

Build:

```
kustomize build --enable-alpha-plugins --as-current-user .
```

Output:

```yaml
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicy
metadata:
  name: storage-admin-policy
  namespace: cnrm-system
spec:
  bindings:
  - members:
    - serviceAccount:mysten-sui.svc.id.goog[monitoring/thanos-compactor]
    role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
  - members:
    - serviceAccount:mysten-sui.svc.id.goog[monitoring/test-compactor]
    role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
  resourceRef:
    apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    kind: IAMServiceAccount
    name: storage-admin
    namespace: cnrm-system
```

If you have other use cases, feel free to create [an issue](https://github.com/aabouzaid/kustomize-plugin-merger/issues) in the project repo.